# Como remover um usuário por inatividade?

Tags: php, session, revisão-de-código

Queria saber como remover um usuário quando ele fica inativo na página, por exemplo no PHPMyAdmin, que remove o usuário após 24 minutos de inatividade?

Se a primeira parte for muito difícil de explicar poderiam pelo menos dizer se este é um código correto para fazer a remoção do usuário inativo? Tem falhas de segurança? Existem possíveis melhorias? Possíveis problemas?

```
<?php
if ( isset($_SESSION['ultimoClick']) && !empty($_SESSION['ultimoClick']) ) {

$tempoAtual = time();

if ( ($tempoAtual - $_SESSION['ultimoClick']) > '900' ) {
session_unset($_SESSION['ultimoClick']);
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("Location:logout.php");
exit();

}else{

$_SESSION['ultimoClick'] = time();

}

}else{

$_SESSION['ultimoClick'] = time();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu código irá destruir a sessão ao fim de 15 minutos.
Apesar da diferença não ser muita, eu faria antes algo deste género:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // 10 minutos em segundos
    $inactive = 600; 

    $session_life = time() - $_session['timeout'];

    if($session_life > $inactive)
    {  session_destroy(); header("Location: logout.php");     }

    S_session['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

---